# Max value from list that is smaller than X

Tags: c#, linq

How to retrieve `int` value from `List` that is biggest number on it but still smaller than `X` value to which i am comparing.

```
Value = 10

Example one: List = {1,4,6,8};  => number 8 biggest on list and smaller than 10
Example two: List = {1,15,17,20}; => number 1 biggest on list and smaller than 10
```

I was trying using Linq but no success so far.

Comment: Are the arrays sorted like in your example? If that is the case you can start going through list and stop when you find a value higher then your limit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just restrict the values you use to get the "Max" by using a `Where` clause:

```
return myList.Where(x => x < 10).Max();
```

Comment: This is the one, I incorrectly thought that you could use the `Max` overload that takes an expression, it seems after testing it that returns a boolean of whether the `Max` is less than said value. Good spot @TimSchmelter

Comment: Problem is that var list = MyLoc.Where(s => s.CurrentLoc < 10).Max(); throws an error: At least one object must implement IComparable.

Comment: @mattytommo: not quite, the overload of [`Enumerable.Max`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535031(v=vs.95).aspx) allows to specify the selector, so which value you want to get the max-value from.  If you specify `x < 10` then you're selecting a `bool` where `true` is "higher" than `false` and you get `true` as result if at least one value is lower than 10.

Comment: `MyLoc.Where(s => s.CurrentLoc < 10).Max()` throws an error because it doesn't know what to be `Max` by, and that wasn't the question you asked, as your lists just had integers. You'd want either `MyLoc.Where(s => s.CurrentLoc < 10).Max(s => s.CurrentLoc)` to get the maximum `CurrentLoc` under 10 or `MyLoc.Where(s => s.CurrentLoc < 10).OrderByDescending(s => s.CurrentLoc).First()` to get an item with such a `CurrentLoc`, but this answer is perfect for the question originally asked.

Comment: Thank you @Jon Hanna for explaining this. Code works now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to filter your values which less than `10` and use [`Max`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get maximum values in them like;

```
var list = new List<int>{1, 15, 17, 20};
list.Where(s => s < 10).Max().Dump();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can  filter items less than x and then find the max by using `Max()` as below

```
list.where(m => m <= x).Max(p => p);
```